# Java script enable a row when a the checkbox is checked

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

there is a tabular form on oracle apex i disabled some columns, i want that when a checkbox is checked only that row's text boxes should be enabled how can i do this in java script.

columns after checkbox are named as below

```
input[name="f07"]
Select[name="f08"]
select[name="f09"]
select[name="f10"]
```

and each rows in the column f08 for example, has ids like below

```
f08_001 and f08_002
```

as below picuture

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for disabling cell in tabular form in Oracle Apex. You can use this also for interactive or clasic reports.
Here is my tabular form:

[image]

Create Dynamic Action (Click) and set proper jQuery selectors using id or class of your checkbox: (my is default .u-TF-item--checkbox)

[image]

Create True action and select execute JavaScript. Below is my JavaScript, just put it into the Code section of the event. Use column header (my is NEWS_TEXT) for selecting specific column!

```
     var
 $checkBox = $(this.triggeringElement);

 if ($checkBox.is(':checked')) {
       $checkBox.closest("tr").find("td[headers=NEWS_TEXT]").find('input').prop('disabled', false);
 }
 else if (!$checkBox.is(':checked')){
     $checkBox.closest("tr").find("td[headers=NEWS_TEXT]").find('input').prop('disabled', true);
 }
```

I hope this will help you. if you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.